# How to set Dropbox startup delay in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dropbox, delay

How to set Dropbox startup delay in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My general solution is this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep $1
shift
exec "$@"
```

Put that somewhere in your `$PATH` in an executable file called "delay". Here's an example of how to use this script:

```
delay 60 dropbox
```

That will wait 60 seconds, then execute dropbox. You can add delays to your startup programs by editing their commands in "Startup Applications".

Comment: delay 60 dropbox Did not work in my Ubuntu. After some reading i found: sh delay 60 dropbox, or: ./delay 60 dropbox That did the job in my box. //TS.

Comment: That's because you didn't put the executable in your `$PATH`.